# Cross thread error despite setting ApartmentState

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to do display the content of a loop to my UI. First off, I'm not sure I'm approaching this the correct way (using WinForms) but this is what I'm doing:

```
foreach (string item in stringArray)
{
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                              {
                                  UpdatedResultEvent(item);
                              });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
}
```

I hope this is enough information, but if it isn't then I'll go into more detail here.

I have 2 classes, my Program.cs (WinForm) and another class called logicClass. I pass an instance of my Program object to my logicClass. My logicClass has a delegate which signature matches a method in my Program class. The method which is passed as a delegate is

```
public void UpdateResultsOnScreen(string newContent)
{
txtResults.Text += newContent;
}
```

The error message is

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread
>   other than the thread it was created on

**EDIT**

The goal is, similar to a way the progress bar works, is to see the Control getting updated in real time. Currently, even if it does work, the thread doesn't return the 'results' to the screen until the thread is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (if you are on WinForms):

```
public void UpdateResultsOnScreen(string newContent)
{
    txtResults.BeginInvoke(
        new Action<string>((value) =>
        {
            txtResults.Text += value;
        }),
        newContent);
}
```

Also as **animaonline** said, consider using `ThreadPool` or `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: This is really good but it doesn't show my results on screen at real time. My textbox still shows everything in one go, instead of populating one item at a time. For example, assume that each time UpdatedResultEvent(item) was called it took 5 seconds (due to database/webservice calls etc). This would mean I'd like my screen to update ever 5 seconds.

Comment: @DaveRook Try my edited code. I think even the old code (`Invoke`) should work and update the UI as you expect, but if it doesn't work, we need to know how you are doing it exactly. I think it should be another question.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried it using BeginInvoke() but the same result. If you think this should work, then maybe else where in my design is a fault!

Comment: @DaveRook Yes, I think it should work. By using a separate thread, you are not blocking the UI thread. And by using the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method, you are sending a message to the UI and telling it to update itself. So it should work, unless you are blocking the UI in some other way, like using `thread.Join()`.

Comment: No, not using thread.Join and not sleeping the thread either. Hmm, must be my code at fault. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking as answered - The call *to* my external CS file was not on a new thread! Now I've ensured it's on a new thread, all is working as desired. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are setting the ApartmentState, the UI controls must be invoked when accessed from another (Non-UI) thread.

Make sure you invoke your UI controls inside your UpdateResultEvent method.

Anyways, what you're doing is not a good idea, consider using a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) or [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx)

It will automatically scale your code, spawning a bunch of threads can really decrease the performance, especially if your collection has a lot of items in it.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this??

```
 public void UpdateResultsOnScreen(string newContent)
    {
        if(txtResults.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtResults.Invoke(
                new Action<string>(content => txtResults.Text += content), newContent);
            return;
        }
        txtResults.Text += newContent;
    }
```